# Fixing gnuradio deleted directory

Tags: gnuradio

I have been following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/gbevan/8e583b9cf87aa3c58102251454fa48a6) to install gnuradio 3.8 onto my Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, but I missed the instruction where it said "Ensure the "gitbranch" is `maint-3.8`", and mine said `maint-3.10`.  After trying to install gr-iqbal, it gave me an error.  For whatever reason, I thought that simply deleting the directory it was built in would let me reinstall it.  It didn't.

I have tried using `pybombs install gnuradio` which gives me `CMake Error: The source directory "/home/aboigoe/sdr/src/gnuradio" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`
I have tried using `pybombs rebuild gnuradio`, but that obtains `Package gnuradio is not installed into current prefix. Aborting.`
To fix that, I tried using `pybombs fetch gnuradio`, which runs fine, but doesn't fix the previous error.
Finally, I tried `pybombs remove gnuradio`, but it says `Package gnuradio is not installed. Aborting.`

Answer (score 0):

So you're working with pybombs! That makes this particular task easier: just delete the whole prefix, and start anew. The main thing you needed to build in that prefix was GNU Radio, and you built 3.10, and wanted 3.8, so that's a complete rebuild, anyways.

I *assume* you're following that guide (which comes, kind of, out of nowhere – GNU Radio has installation guides on their wiki, https://wiki.gnuradio.org) because you **want** exactly GNU Radio 3.8, with gr-osmosdr and gr-iqbal.

If you just want a working GNU Radio that can talk to your SDR hardware, um, don't follow random guides from the internet :) Instead, your whole problem boils down to a simple

```bash
sudo apt install gnuradio
```

and that's it – GNU Radio 3.10, as Ubuntu 22.04 ships it, contains gr-soapy, and Ubuntu's `apt` will install many available hardware drivers (for RTL-SDR, hackrf, mirisdr, bladerf, audio-interfaced hardware, red pitaya,…) without any need to do anything yourself. It just works.

The thing that will be different is that the blocks to inteface with your hardware will not reside under the "osmosd" category in your GRC, but in "Soapy", but I guess you'll deal with that rather than going through the rather convoluted way of installing an old (and not updated anymore) version of GNU Radio, to include an old (and not updated anymore) version of gr-osmosdr :)